# Convert following code from C to VB.NET

Tags: c, vb.net

Hey guys,
Can you please give me a hand to convert the following C code into VB.NET. I have a feeling it would be pretty simple... but my C knowledge is very very limited!

Any help would be great!
Thanks

```
buf[0] = (num1 & 0xff000000) >> 24;  
buf[1] = (num1 & 0xff0000) >> 16;  
buf[2] = (num1 & 0xff00) >> 8;  
buf[3] =  num1 & 0xff;

buf[4] = (num2 & 0xff000000) >> 24;  
buf[5] = (num2 & 0xff0000) >> 16;  
buf[6] = (num2 & 0xff00) >> 8;  
buf[7] =  num2 & 0xff;  

strncpy(buf+8, headers->key3, 8);  
buf[16] = '\0';  

md5_buffer(buf, 16, target);  
target[16] = '\0';
```

Comment: Since you consistently talk about C, I changed the `c++` tag to `c`. Feel free to edit your text and tag if you really meant C++.

Comment: The code marshals the bytes of two 4-byte values into a buffer, in big endian order (i.e. highest byte first). Then it copies some (at most) 8 long string after them. Finally it apparently calculates an MD5 hash from the resulting 16 bytes(?) Dunno how that translates to VB, but hope this helps.

Comment: Basically yes! The code should take "Key1" which is 4 bytes, and concatenate it with "Key2" which is also 4 bytes and put them in big endian order. The code should then add a 8 byte string to the end, and calculate an MD5 hash of those 16 bytes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
byte[] temp1 = BitConvert.GetBytes(num1);
byte[] temp2 = BitConvert.GetBytes(num2);

Array.Copy(temp1, 0, buf, 0, 4);
Array.Copy(temp2, 0, buf, 4, 4);

Array.Copy(buf, 8, headers.key3, 0, 8)
buf[16] = 0;

Array.Copy(buf, target, 16)
target[16] = 0;

Using MD5 hasher = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
    target = hasher.ComputeHash(buf);
End Using
```

Comment: Consider (only know C#): `byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(num1); bytes[0..3]` Also, the order returned *depends upon machine layout*.

Comment: In C# (again, don't know VB), this has a more direct endian-neutral representation: `buf[0] = (byte)((num1 >> 24) & 0xff);` Note mask is done *after* shift and a cast is used.